# Sharing updated machine with others using vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I have just updated my VM which I created using vagrant. I have also installed java7-jdk.
We are 3 people on team and I want to share current status of machine with them. What is the right procedure to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to share/distribute is to package (export) the boxes to `.box` (gzipped tar) files.

To export the box:

`vagrant package --base box_name --output /path/to/share.box`

See more info here: [Package](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html)

Comment: what is the difference between exporting vagrant managed machine and virtualbox managed machine?

Comment: vagrant wraps the `VBoxManage` (as well as tools like `veewee`) command to make it easier to use. So basically `vagrant package` is calling `VBoxManage export` => http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-export

Comment: I am thinking about packaging my existing opensuse 64 bit VM then which I created in virtualbox couple of weeks ago. Is it really that simple to export the machine and share? I just started using vagrant today so don't know much yet.

Comment: Yep, you can try packaging it and consume it on a different machine with vagrant + virtualbox, no risk at all. I've hancrafted several vagrant boxes as well as automated the building using veewee, I am sure you'll be amazed.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to veewee. Now I regret why I didn't investigate vagrant further when I first heard about it from a friend 2 years ago. I thought it was just another virtualization software like virtualbox. Life would have been bit easier if I had read more about it.